# How is control of the airplane passed from one pilot to another?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, accidents, pilots

In both the [Tenerife accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_airport_disaster) in 1977 and the [Air Florida accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Florida_Flight_90) in 1982, the first officer (FO) in the cockpit opposed the decision of the captain to take off. What should the FO do if the captain is determined to do the wrong - possibly even the fatal - thing?

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe.  The linked question does not address the core question here - `What should the FO do if the captain is determined to do the wrong - possibly even the fatal - thing?`

Comment: That's a [CMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_resource_management) (Crew/Cockpit Resource Management) issue. Whether the core question is what the FO should do, the other question is somewhat related, while being the other way around (giving control and the other not acknowledging). Fair enough, while the Wikipedia is a good answer start, I won't do the copy/paste. Not really a duplicate IMHO, but borderline. Both questions should merge or we'll need at least 8 questions to cover most scenarios.

Comment: [Another one (How are conflicts between pilot flying and pilot not-flying over aircraft control resolved?)](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/5091/3879) deeply related, if not the generic case of the issue.

Comment: @Simon Well, the last sentence in the linked question seems to me to cover exactly that point, and the last sentence of the [currently accepted answer](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/5093/62) seems to answer it. Of course, if the FO (or PNF) chooses not to follow the protocols and physically opposes the captain then that's a very different scenario but it's so extreme that I don't know if there's any 'standard' answer or explanation.

Comment: The linked answer is *not* a duplicate. The linked answer addresses the "my plane/your plane" protocols.  This question is explicitly about the "We all agree it's your plane and you're taking off *without clearance*!" type situation