# Why is the autopilot called "George?"

Tags: autopilot, terminology, aviation-history

The autopilot of an airplane is frequently referred to as "George" (for example, in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/5076/909)). When did this nickname enter common usage, and what is its origin? Please cite sources if possible!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The first "practical" autopilot was invented by George DeBeeson ([the patent can be found here](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect2=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PALL&RefSrch=yes&Query=PN/1829790), updated [here](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect2=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PALL&RefSrch=yes&Query=PN/2146800)) - This seems to be the most likely reason for the informal name "George" for the autopilot system on aircraft.

Autopilots are also sometimes called "Otto" (as in [Otto the Autopilot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQbj9uvYL8I) from *Airplane!*, and [our very own chat bot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users/322/otto-the-autopilot), but this seems to be less common than "George".

Comment: Don't forget Otto from Wall-E ! (Actually it could be "Auto" there, but to me they sound just about the same.)

Comment: Audible warning systems are often called "Bitchin' Betty@.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that the Pullman railcar of America ran an advert at the turn oh the 19 century  "let George do it"

Source: https://h2g2.com/edited_entry/A87996172

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have any source that links that to aviation?

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps from the Old Tyme Radio Show "Let George Do It!" wherein the hero hired himself out to do jobs too tough for his customers.

Comment: This answer appears to be little more than speculation. Are there any references you can cite which would support your proposed answer?

Answer (score -3):

The term "George" as a reference to autopilots originated in the RAF in WWII.  It is a reference to the aircraft's "owner" King George.  Also, at the time, there was a popular radio show referenced in an earlier answer that may have reinforced the use of "George". I have spoken to a number of British WWII pilots. Everyone assumed it was a reference to King George.  None of these pilots were aware of the name of the inventor of the earliest autopilot.  They were, however, aware of the name Sperry.

Comment: You should provide links and references to improve your answer.

Comment: Who is “Sperry” and why is that relevant?